# AJAX :call a specific function from another page

Tags: php, ajax, function, oop

I have 2 files:

1. user.php and
2. index.php

In `index.php` I'm creating new user object: `user_home` and calling `user.php`

like this and it works:

```
function showUsers()
$user_home->showUsers()
```

How to do it with `AJAX` in objective way, without refreshing a page.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is javascript and is running in client navigator, not on serveur. So you cant run PHP rirectly after page il loaded.

The solution is to create a php script to generate only the unser informations (call $user_home->showUsers()) and call this script with javascript

```js
function getUser(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://PATH_TO_YOUR_NEW_PHP_SCRIPT"
    success:function(data){
      $('#user_infos').innerHtml(data);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="user_infos"></div>
```